# Back button to return to state of dynamically added controls

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form that uses JavaScript to add controls to the form. For example, when a button on the form is clicked, a textbox is added to the form.

When the user submits the form, the user is taken to another view. However, if the user clicks the back button on the browser, s/he is taken to the previous form (having the button to add controls) but none of the textbox s/he had added dynamically earlier is showing up. However, the other static form controls show up with the data previously entered.

How can I have it such that pressing the back button returns to a complete previous state?
Or do I need to implement this in a custom button? How can I do that?

Comment: jpo, I was wondering, did my answer work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am actually have not yet. doesn't  sessionstorage refresh as the page reloads making it to loss its values?

Comment: whoops, mixed it up with `localStorage`. That's the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` should be suitable, here.

1. When the user adds a input field, save the fact it was added, as well as it's value, to the `sessionStorage`
2. When the user presses "back", check if any fields are saved in the `sessionStorage`, if that's the case,
3. Re-build the form, depending on the added fields in the storage,
4. Don't forget to remove a entry from the storage, if a field is removed.

Some pseudo-code:

```
function fieldAdded(name, value){
    sessionStorage[name] = value;
    // You can also use this function to update the saved value, when fields are edited.
}

function pageLoad(name, value){ // load event after pressing "back"
    var optionalFields = ['telephone','fax','name','description'];
    for(var i = 0; i < optionalFields.length; i++){
        if(sessionStorage[optionalFields[i]]){
            // addField(Name, value);
            addField(optionalFields[i], sessionStorage[optionalFields[i]]);
        }
    }
}

function fieldRemoved(name){
    delete sessionStorage[name];
}
```